# Flutter- How to handle deeplinking in Flutter without using router

Tags: flutter, firebase, deep-linking

I'm attempting to build deeplink functionality and so far the initial start of the app and retrieving parameters from the deeplink is going fine.

However I am having issues navigating to a screen after I deeplink into the app. How should I do this?

I am using navigator instead of router, I want to open MenuDetailPage after updating link-

```
Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (BuildContext context) => MenuDetailPage(
                                          name: snapshot.data!.data[index]!.name,
                                          product: snapshot.data!.data[index].id,
                                        ),
                                      ),),
```

What will be the link in firebase?- https://dummyapp.page.link/start